# Something wrong with my Comeonin.bcrypt code for password hashing

Tags: elixir, importerror, password-hash

So I'm using `Phoenix` latest version and Comeonin 5.0 and bcrypt_elixir 2.0 for hashing my password but somehow it's not able to use my current function which I'm using and it's showing that it's undefined.

Because the function is changed now before I was using `hashpwsalt(pass`) to pass my password to create a hash. But now I'm using `hash_pwd_salt(pass)`. But it's still showing me the error.

```
defp put_password_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}}
        ->
          put_change(changeset, :password_hash, hash_pwd_salt(pass))
      _ ->
          changeset
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error I'm getting when I try to run my server :

> **cannot import Comeonin.Bcrypt.hash_pwd_salt/1 because it is undefined or private**

Please take a look at my code and tell me what changes I can do?

Comment: Looking at [this tutorial](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/blob/master/guides/tutorial/start-tutorial.md), seems like you can add `alias Argon2` at the beginning of the module, and then call the function as `Argon2.hash_pwd_salt(pass)`. Does that sound like what you're trying to do?

Comment: BTW, by the error message it sounds like you have a line saying `import Comeonin.Bcrypt, only: [hash_pwd_salt: 1]`, but that doesn't work because `Comeonin.Bcrypt` doesn't have a function by that name, only `hashpwsalt` (see [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/comeonin/Comeonin.Bcrypt.html#hashpwsalt/2)).

Comment: Change `import Comeonin.Bcrypt, only: [hash_pwd_salt: 1]` to `import Bcrypt, only: [hash_pwd_salt: 1]`

Comment: @legoscia I did all those changes but it doesn't work. I checked the documentation

Comment: @SiddhantSingh could you please include all the code necessary to reproduce the problem, otherwise it will be difficult for people to help you further.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I already solved the problem. But Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there's no single parameter function `hash_pwd_salt/1`. There's a `hash_pwd_salt/2`, and the 2nd parameter is optional.

Here's [the source](http://om/riverrun/bcrypt_elixir/blob/master/lib/bcrypt.ex#L136-L144) for that function in v2.0 of `Bcrypt`:

```
  def hash_pwd_salt(password, opts \\ []) do
    Base.hash_password(
      password,
      gen_salt(
        Keyword.get(opts, :log_rounds, Application.get_env(:bcrypt_elixir, :log_rounds, 12)),
        Keyword.get(opts, :legacy, false)
      )
    )
end
```

Note that if you alias the module instead, you don't need to the the arity of the function.

E.g., put `alias Comeonin.Bcrypt` near the top of your file, and then specify the module when calling the function like this: `Bcrypt.hash_pwd_salt(pass)`